# R "Object notfound " error

Tags: r

this code executes perfectly.

```
 v1 <- 8:17
```

but this code gives me the error underneath.

```
 V1[V1 < 12 | V1 > 15]
Error: object 'V1' not found
```

What am I doing wrong. I am fairly new to the R programming.

Comment: You are using a lower case `v` the first time and an upper case `V` the second time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable names are case-sensitive. You used `v1` in the first line, not the same as `V1` (upper-case V) in the second.

Comment: perfect. it works. thank you so much